# How do I simulate the Windows Run command from a command prompt?

Tags: windows, unc, runas

Let's say I click Start -> Run, and enter "\\10.0.0.27". This will launch an Explorer window navigating to that machine and showing any shares available on it.

However, I'd like to perform this action using different user credentials than the currently logged-in user. So, I thought I could launch a command window and then start the process from there.

How do I do that?

Comment: From my understanding, unlike most other programs, the explorer can't be started with `runas` as a different user due to a deliberate restriction since Vista. You could try to use an alternative file manager.

Comment: @Sven I was indeed thinking about the restriction where you can't launch a second copy of Explorer (and by virtue of that, can't `runas` another one), but wondered if there was a way around it. In any case, you most most definitely CAN start Explorer as a different user, you just have to force quit Explorer first.

Comment: If the currently logged on user has no permissions to the share at all, you will get prompted for credentials when trying to browse to a UNC path.

Answer (score 2):

You can't launch Explorer as a different user (at least not without killing the one you are currently using), but you *can* connect to a network share using different credentials.

Just use the "Map Network Drive" function in Windows Explorer and check the box to use different credentials; you'll be able to keep using the same Explorer, but the actual network connection will be made with the credentials you'll supply.